# RethinkDB and Node.js/Express - Opening multiple connections for parallel queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rethinkdb

Is there a better way to run parallel queries with the RethinkDB Node driver than opening multiple connections per request? Or is this actually a good way of going about what I need? I'd prefer to stay away from connection pools/third-party packages. The app in question has a singleton containing functions that wrap RethinkDB queries. Those functions handle creating and closing connections. This pattern allows me to require the database service in multiple routers with minimal overhead and without it having to know about each request. Contrived example to explain how unrelated the data may be that gets queried:

database.js

```
var r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports = {

    getApples: function(callback) {
        r.connect(/* config */)
            .then(function(conn){
                r.db('fruitDatabase').table('apples').run(conn)
                    .then(function(cursor){
                        return cursor.toArray();
                    })
                    .then(function(apples){
                        return callback(null, apples);
                    })
                    .finally(function(){
                        return conn.close();
                    });
            });
    },
    getPotatoes: function(callback) {
        r.connect(/* config */)
            .then(function(conn){
                r.db('vegetableDatabase').table('potatoes').run(conn)
                    .then(function(cursor){
                        return cursor.toArray();
                    })
                    .then(function(potatoes){
                        return callback(null, potatoes);
                    })
                    .finally(function(){
                        return conn.close();
                    });
            });
    }
};
```

Now, I need to create a page/endpoint that displays all the apples and all the potatoes, so I currently call both of those functions via async.parallel in my page router:

pages.js

```
var pages = require('express').Router(),
    async = require('async'),
    db = require('./database');

pages.route('/food')
    .get(function(req, res, next){
        async.parallel({
            apples: db.getApples,
            potatoes: db.getPotatoes
        }, function(err, data){
            if(err) return next(err);

            res.render('food',
                {
                    apples: data.apples,
                    potatoes: data.potatoes
                });
        });
    });
```

Thoughts? What if it were 4 connections opened in parallel (or many more)?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot wait for the official driver to get a connection pool, You could also use a middleware to open a connection for each request, as in [this example](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/examples/node-todo/) from the official doc :

```
app.use(createConnection);                      // Create a RethinkDB connection

function createConnection(req, res, next) {
    r.connect(config.rethinkdb, function(error, conn) {
        if (error) {
            handleError(res, error);
        }
        else {
            // Save the connection in `req`
            req._rdbConn = conn;
            // Pass the current request to the next middleware
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that RethinkDB can handle many parallel connections just fine. It also maybe easier to work with. If you use a share connection for all, we have to deal with re-try to connect when connection break, and have to ensure it is open throught the life cycle of request or the sever.

This RethinkDB driver https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash runs every query on its own connection.

> The driver execute one query per connection. Now that rethinkdb/rethinkdb#3296 is solved, this behavior may be changed in the future.

More than that, if you ever bring change feed into your app, you will be very likely want change feed on its own connection according to http://docs.rethinkdb.com/2.1/api/javascript/changes/

> It’s a good idea to open changefeeds on their own connection. If you  don’t, other queries run on the same connection will experience unpredictable latency spikes while the connection blocks on more changes.

So, in other word, I say go ahead and let's make it simple and easier by using many parallel connections.

Comment: Ah, indeed it can handle multiple parallel connections just fine. I should have clarified in my question that I was referring to multiple connections per request, versus the typical one-per-request pattern or a connection pool. Editing the question to reflect this. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -1):

I believe the information on this answer is out of date. I have opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296377/are-connection-pools-still-recommended)